# How to commit list of ignore files with Android Studio using TFS plugin

Tags: android-studio, tfs, jetbrains-ide, ignore, tfignore

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 with
TFS Integration by JetBrains Version: 173.3415.27

I have .tfignore files but TFS Integration plugin does not utilize it. .tfignore file support has been requested to plugin but that doesn't seem to go anywhere: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206854665-IntelliJ-IDEA-13-TFS-tfignore

AFAIK only place ignore files are listed is workspace.xml which is not recommended to be commited into source control.

Is there a way to commit list of ignored files to source control using TFS Integration by JetBrains?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to share internal Ignore files list.

The link you referenced is just a forum thread. Here is the request in the tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125729 Does not look like a popular one.